# How to create a launch file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone!!

How can i create a launch file?

As a sample, have a look at turtlemimic.launch

```
<launch>

  <group ns="turtlesim1">
    <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
  </group>

  <group ns="turtlesim2">
    <node pkg="turtlesim" name="sim" type="turtlesim_node"/>
  </group>

  <node pkg="turtlesim" name="mimic" type="mimic">
    <remap from="input" to="turtlesim1/turtle1"/>
    <remap from="output" to="turtlesim2/turtle1"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

However, how do I get this working ?

Best,

Vincent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62743/how-to-create-a-launch-file?/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carrie Yan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30264/carrie-yan/) on 2017-05-04**:
start with **$ gedit turtlemimic.launch**, then a new window with gedit will pop up, just paste those stuff, save and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launch file is useful when you want to start/launch many nodes at once without any need to do "rosrun for every node".

In the package, create a folder by the name launch and create a filename.launch file.

It always start with

```
 <launch>
```

and if some parameters should be set then

```
<param name="use_sim_time"  value="true" />
```

To start a node

```
<node pkg="name_of_package" type="name_of_packge" name="name_of_executable" 
output="screen"/>
```

Example

```
<node pkg="sure_on_cloud" type="estimate_transform_svd" name="estimate_transform_svd" 
output="screen"/>
```

In the above way, one can call multiple nodes from different packages.

Nodelets can also be initialized. Sorry I dont know what they are, but they can also be initialized from the example below

```
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager"/>

 <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="point_cloud_xyz"
    args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz standalone_nodelet">
```

Some packages have their topics already set to specific names. They can be remapped to different names.

```
<remap from="/image_rect" to="/camera/depth/image"/>
<remap from="/points" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
<remap from="/camera_info" to="/camera/depth/camera_info"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-03-15**:
launching a node worked for me after a slight modification

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-09-13**:
http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet
// Just if someone wants to read about what nodelets are

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What program could I create a filename.launch?

---

Originally posted by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) with karma: 52 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-15**:
i didnt get u

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-15**:
@vncntmh write the launch file in gedit and save it with a .launch extension ! was that your issue ?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-15**:\

gedit turtlemimic.launch, and save in /Home/catkin_ws/beginner_tutorials/launch/

(http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch)

But I have problem when I used:

roscd beginner_tutorials

roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-15**:
It means that beginner_tutorials is not in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. One solution is to add the path to the beginner tutorials or the workspace to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. You can search how to change ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in ROS. Beat way is to create a overlay http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-15**:
@Sai Thanks!!!

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-15**:
now, I have this problem:

roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch

[beginner_tutorials] is not a package or launch file name

I have beginner_tutorials in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH (fuerte_workspace) and I used:

gedit turtlemimic.launch

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-15**:
I am guessing that there might be some problem in creating the package. May be manifest file is missing or something else. Even though it is in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, it is not a package..To know if it is in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, just roscd filename, shold take you there.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-15**:
Redo the package creation process once again following the tutorials

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-15**:
I have a question, what is the different between:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

(cd ~/catkin_ws/beginner_tutorials), I think that my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is catkin

And this:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch

(roscd beginner_tutorials),

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-15**:
roscd is used to go to any package in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH from any location. I think both are same. Ex: cd /..path to package../beginner_tutorials is equivalent to roscd beginner_tutorials

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-05-15**:
me too, and how could I add beginner_tutorials to my package?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-05-15**:
Go thru the tutorials from beginning ..U can create a package and design how it shud work..and moreover there should not be two answers to a question. If you have any questions for a given answer or question try to add comments and get it solved

**Comment by [Waleed](https://answers.ros.org/users/29546/waleed/) on 2017-03-09**:
I did not understand, Why to set parameters in launch file? what are those parameters

**Comment by [Hemanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/39363/hemanth/) on 2019-12-02**:
To fix this error:

```
 roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch [beginner_tutorials] is not a package or launch file name
```

source your workspace through the command

```
source ws_name/devel/setup.bash
```

or
add the same line to your .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To Solve This Problem :

```
roscd beginner_tutorials

roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'
```

Simply go to the command terminal and type in :

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Go to the end of the list and add :

```
source /home/Your_Path_name/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Close and Save.

Go to Command line again and type

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Run again `roscd` and Viola! :)

---

Originally posted by [Robotronics](https://answers.ros.org/users/49773/robotronics/) with karma: 21 on 2019-11-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1